# Can't pass std::min to function, copy of std::min works

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, overload-resolution

Passing `std::min` to a function does not compile. I copied the libcpp declaration of `std::min` into my source file and it works.

What's wrong with the std version? Same happens with clang and gcc. Tested on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/g/zwRqUA

```
#include <thread>
#include <algorithm>

namespace mystd {
    // declaration copied verbatim from std::min (libcpp 4.0)
    template <class _Tp> inline constexpr const _Tp&
    mymin(const _Tp& __a, const _Tp& __b)
    {
        return std::min(__a, __b);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread thr1(std::min<int>, 2, 3); // compile error
    std::thread thr2(mystd::mymin<int>, 2, 3); // works
    return 0;
}
```

The errors for clang and gcc:

```
[x86-64 clang 5.0.0 #1] error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::thread'

[x86-64 gcc 7.2 #1] error: no matching function for call to 'std::thread::thread(<unresolved overloaded function type>, int, int)'
[x86-64 gcc 7.2 #1] note:   couldn't deduce template parameter '_Callable'
```

Comment: The function is overloaded for one template parameter.

Comment: The error message you get looks to me like it already tells you what's wrong.

Comment: And what's the error, please?

Comment: Errors appended to question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two template functions `min` overloaded for one template parameter. They are

```
template<class T> constexpr const T& min(const T& a, const T& b);
```

and

```
template<class T>
constexpr T min(initializer_list<T> t);
```

So the compiler does not know which one to select.

You could use an explicit casting of the function pointer to tell the compiler which function you mean.

Or you could use an intermediate pointer. For example

```
const int & ( *operation )( const int &, const int & ) = std::min<int>;
```

And then use the pointer `operation` instead of the function `std::min`.

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap `std::min` in a lambda, like this:

```
std::thread thr1([](int a, int b) { return std::min(a, b); }, 2, 3);
```

It doesn't work without the lambda wrapper because of the template argument ambiguity, just like @Vlad from Moscow explained.