# c++ how to pass min() and max() as as constructor argument?

Tags: c++, function, templates

I have a class `MyClass`, which will use either `min()` or `max()` based on what argument is taken during construction,

```
class MyClass {
private:
    myfunc;
public:
    MyClass(args);
}
```

Later `myfunc` will be used in another method in `MyClass`, and I would like `args` can be used to initialize `myfunc` to be either `max` or `min`, wondering how to achieve that? or maybe other way I can set `myfunc` to be either `max` or `min` will be fine too.

Comment: What are `min()` and `max()`? The `std::min()` and `std::max()` from `<algorithm>`? or something else?

Comment: Anyway, you want to research _function pointers_, and bear in mind complications added when templates exist, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47109317/cant-pass-stdmin-to-function-copy-of-stdmin-works).

Comment: NOTE: on windows `min` and `max` are squatted on by macros defined in the windows headers. If you want to use `std::min` and `std::max` you need to define `NOMINMAX` before `windows.h` however doing so may break some headers such as MFC.

Comment: If `min` and `max` are referring to `std::min` and `std::max`, they are not functions. They're templates. You could use `std::min<int>`, for example, but the raw templates can't be members of a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    const bool isMax;

public:
    MyClass( bool ax ) : isMax( ax ) { }

    template<class E>
    E apply( E a, E b ) const
    {
        if( isMax )
            return std::max( a, b );
        else
            return std::min( a, b );
    }
};
```

Technically doable with a function pointer, or `std::function`, however these are probably slower. They compile into indirect jumps. This version compiles into a regular branch. Because the flag never changes, from the CPU’s point of view the outcome is very predictable.